# Pyinstaller error no module name pywintypes

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, pyinstaller

Good day, I've been trying to turn a .py script to a .exe, I've run the following command: "python pyinstaller.py EyeBreak.py" in cmd and got an error: ImportError: no module named wintypes, looking at the questions on SO I downloaded the .dll file and placed it in the same folder as pyinstaller, but i still get the same error. How can I fix this? Is there a better way to turn a .py to a .exe?
Here is my code if relevant: https://github.com/Faresalghazy/EyeBreak/blob/master/eyebreak.py

Comment: Which version of pyinstaller?

Comment: pyinstaller3.2, downloaded from the website yesterday

Comment: Using the development tip of pyinstaller I was able to buuild an exe on windows 7.  Suggest you consult: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong and
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs

Comment: Thanks Stephen, link was useful